# All numbers always detected as odd

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_list_even(my_list):
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] % 2 == 1:
            return False
        else:
            return True

def is_list_odd(my_list):
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] % 2 == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    if is_list_even(my_list):
        print("all even")
    elif is_list_odd(my_list):
        print("all odd")
    else:
        print("not even or odd")
```

I'm trying to get the certain output "not even or odd" but it only shows up as "all odd". I've been looking at it for awhile and wondering if anyone could help me see where I'm making my mistake.

Comment: What is the input you expect to produce this output from?  *Why* should it produce that output, and what is the *first* line that behaves differently than you expected?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through your code. Make sure it does what you expect it to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You return too early:

```
def is_list_even(my_list):
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] % 2 == 1:
            return False
    return True  # only once you checked all of them, you know that!
```

Also, generally no need for working with indexes. Python's for-loop is a for-each loop already:

```
def is_list_odd(my_list):
    for x in my_list:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

The built-in utils for that short-circuiting idiom are [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) or [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
def is_list_even(my_list):
    return not any(x % 2 == 1 for x in my_list)
    # return all(x % 2 == 0 for x in my_list)

def is_list_odd(my_list):
    return not any(x % 2 == 0 for x in my_list)
    # return all(x % 2 == 1 for x in my_list)
```